# Write Large Image as PDF in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, pdf

I am trying to write a large image to PDF (141"x24" at 300 DPI, so 42300 pixels x 7200 pixels). I can write the image as a png without a problem using `imwrite()`. However, `imwrite()` does not provide PDF as an output option. So, the alternatives I have seen online all do something like this:

```
pdffig = figure;
set(pdffig,'Units','Inches','Position',[0 0 141 24],'PaperSize',[141 24]);
pdfaxs = axes;
imshow(Im,'Parent',pdfaxs);
print(pdffig,'largeimage.pdf','-dpdf');
```

This code is creating a figure, setting some properties to make the figure 141x24 inches in size, showing the image on the figure axis, and then printing the figure contents to pdf.

Unfortunately, what happens is that the figure is resized to fit my screen when `imshow()` is called and then the printed pdf will have a small version of the image in the center of a large white pdf. What I actually want is for the image to take up the entire 141"x24" pdf. I have tried rearranging when the window size is set and when `imshow()` is called, but that doesn't help. Note that this works if the desired PDF size fits on my screen (e.g. if I was printing a 12"x12" PDF).

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: What is in the figure? If it's an actual image, what are you hoping to achieve by saving as PDF, since it will still be a pixel-based image? If it's a plot you've created then you don't need to make it so huge, saving it as a PDF will preserve the vector graphics and you can zoom to your heart's content.

Comment: Hi @Wolfie, the figure is a large image of size 42300 pixels x 7200 pixels. It is an algorithmically generated image that I want to give to others so they can print with a poster plotter. PDF is one of the accepted formats which also bakes in the DPI, length, and width information. So, the goal is just so make a 141" x 24" PDF that is completely filled with this generated image.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but this sounds a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - like if your algorithm generated a vector graphic instead of a bitmap then you might find some big advantages in file size, PDF generation, and compatibility with plotters.